# CakePHP setJsonEncodeFormat not functioning as expected

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, icu, intl

In my CakePHP bootstrap.php I have the following:

```
use Cake\I18n\Date;
use Cake\I18n\FrozenDate;
use Cake\I18n\FrozenTime;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

Time::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

When in an API method I do the following:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;

$time = new Time();

$this->set([
    'time' => $time,
    '_serialize' => ['time']
]);
```

The result is something like this:

```
{
  "time": "2017-05-16 11.55.13"
}
```

Note the incorrect time format. For some reason CakePHP/PHP 7/Linux changes the `:` to a `.`. On Windows it works fine.

CakePHP version => `3.4.6` (although this problem has been there a long time)

PHP Version => `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`

Comment: This may help you. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html

Comment: Is there something I'm missing? I've done what that page suggests for changing the json output but it's not working...

Comment: What's your ICU version (`\INTL_ICU_VERSION`)? Make sure that you're using at least 56.1

Comment: My version is 55.1. Now the question is, can it be upgraded to a newer version on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I don't really know... I guess you could always build it from source. You could also try escaping the colon: `':'`, normally that should avoid it from being interpreted as a pattern character, which could possibly be the problem.

Comment: I've tried escaping, the result is something like `"created": "2014-05-28 13\\.27\\.10"`

Thanks for the help. I'll see about building from source.

Comment: You need to [**use single quotes for escaping**](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax), my `':'` from above was an example of that.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer as provided by @ndm:

At least in ICU versions prior to 56.1, the correct way to use setJsonEncodeFormat is to escape the colon with `'` like so:

```
Time::setJsonEncodeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
Date::setJsonEncodeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```